Roblox Knockback Skipping Waypoint
I am creating a knockback script for a Roblox tower defense game that is meant to teleport an enemy backwards toward another part by 5 studs. The knockback function works for this purpose, but after being pushed back, the enemy skips the waypoint it is moving towards. Enemies in this game move along the track by moving from waypoint blocks to waypoint blocks. When the knockback occurs, the enemy moves diagonally off the track toward the next waypoint instead of the one it is supposed to move to.
So far, I have attempted to use a BindableEvent to set the enemy's waypoint target back by one, but it is having no effect on its corner-cutting movement. Here is the code for my knockback script:
task.wait(10)
local target = game:GetService("Workspace")["Live Enemies"]["Handcuff Arrest Officer"]

local waypoint: Part = nil
if target.EnemyInfo.Waypoint.Value == 0 then
    waypoint = game:GetService("Workspace").SpawnPoint
else
    waypoint = game:GetService("Workspace").Waypoints[target.EnemyInfo.Waypoint.Value]
end
local studsToMove = 5

-- Make sure the model has a PrimaryPart set
if target.PrimaryPart then
    -- Calculate direction from target's PrimaryPart to waypoint
    local direction = (waypoint.Position - target.PrimaryPart.Position).unit

    -- Calculate the new position, moving the PrimaryPart 5 studs in the direction of the waypoint
    local newPosition = target.PrimaryPart.Position + direction * studsToMove

    -- Offset the entire model by the same movement, preserving its orientation
    target.Knockback:Fire()
    target:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(target.PrimaryPart.CFrame + (direction * studsToMove))
end

Additionally, here is the code for the enemy movement script. It uses a no-timeout version of humanoid:MoveTo() from https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid.
-- In case the enemy dies before this script can run, pcall blocks errors.
pcall(function(...)
    -- Constants
    local humanoid = script.Parent.Humanoid
    local info = script.Parent.EnemyInfo
    local waypoints = game:GetService("Workspace").Waypoints
    local waypoints_hit = 0 -- Not constant, waypoint counter
    local knockback = script.Parent.Knockback
    
    -- MoveTo() without timeout
    local function moveTo(humanoid, targetPoint)
        local targetReached = false
        local connection
        connection = humanoid.MoveToFinished:Connect(function(reached)
            targetReached = true
            print("Reached target "..tostring(targetPoint))
            connection:Disconnect()
            connection = nil
        end)
        humanoid:MoveTo(targetPoint)
        while not targetReached do
            if not (humanoid and humanoid.Parent) then
                break
            end
            if humanoid.WalkToPoint ~= targetPoint then
                break
            end
            humanoid:MoveTo(targetPoint)
            task.wait(0.1)
        end
        if connection then
            connection:Disconnect()
            connection = nil
        end
    end
    
    knockback.Event:Connect(function(...: any)
        print("Fired")
        waypoints_hit -= 1
        script.Parent.EnemyInfo.Waypoint.Value = tostring(waypoints_hit)
        if waypoints_hit == 0 then
            moveTo(humanoid, game:GetService("Workspace").SpawnPoint.Position)
        else
            moveTo(humanoid, game:GetService("Workspace").Waypoints[waypoints_hit].Position)
        end
    end)

    -- Enemy configurations
    local damage: number = info.Damage.Value -- Damage to base
    local hp: number = info.HP.Value -- Hit points
    local speed: number = info.Speed.Value -- Speed
    
    -- Set HP and speed
    humanoid.MaxHealth = hp
    humanoid.Health = hp
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = speed
    
    -- Move
    for i,v in pairs(waypoints:GetChildren()) do
        moveTo(humanoid, v.Position)
        waypoints_hit += 1
        script.Parent.EnemyInfo.Waypoint.Value = tostring(waypoints_hit)
        if waypoints_hit >= 8 then
            game:GetService("Workspace")["Match Config"].BaseHP.Value -= damage
            script.Parent:Destroy()
        end
    end
end)

I found out that humanoid:MoveTo() stops when the root part's CFrame is changed, which is what I am doing to facilitate knockback. However, I'm not sure how to get around this limitation, which I need to do for the knockback feature. Any help would be appreciated!

Your code does a good job setting up a list of waypoints for your enemy to walk along, and you already have the foundation for changing targets. But the logic that decides when to switch waypoints just needs to be a bit smarter.
So let's walk through the way a knockback along a path should work :



Description
Diagram




Consider the path ABC:  - A is the spawn point, and C is the end point,  - the distance from A to B is 10 studs,  - the distance from B to C is 15.



Let's imagine we have an enemy marching from B to C, and they are 3 studs past B...



When the enemy is knocked back 5 studs...  - they should be sent back the 3 studs to B,  - then the remaining 2 studs should send them towards A.




So one way to represent this process is with simple distance calculations. You subtract the distance from the enemy to their last waypoint until the distance to the next waypoint is greater than the remaining knockback, then just place the enemy along the points again. If you make it back to the beginning, just escape and set the enemy back at the spawn point
So your knockback logic needs to know the following information :

the full list of waypoints
the enemy's current waypoint target
the enemy's current position
how far to be knocked back

Let's make a ModuleScript to handle your Enemy logic. The updated knockback logic will live in the Enemy:OnKnockback() function, which you can trigger however you like later.
local Enemy = {}
Enemy.__index = Enemy

function Enemy.new(waypoints : { BasePart }, damage : number, speed : number, health : number, modelTemplate : Model)
    assert(#waypoints >= 2, "List of waypoints must be >= 2")
    
    local self = {
        waypoints = waypoints,
        currentWaypoint = 2, -- assume that 1 is the spawn, so the first target is 2
        damage = damage,
        speed = speed,
        health = health,
        modelTemplate = modelTemplate,
        moveToConnection = nil, -- for now
        modelRef = nil, -- for now
    }
    setmetatable(self, Enemy)
    return self
end

function Enemy:Spawn()
    local newModel = self.modelTemplate:Clone()
    newModel.Humanoid.Health = self.health
    newModel.Humanoid.MaxHealth = self.health
    newModel.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = self.speed
    newModel:PivotTo(self.waypoints[1].CFrame)
    newModel.Parent = game.Workspace

    self.modelRef = newModel
end

function Enemy:Walk()
    if (self.moveToConnection) then
        self.moveToConnection:Disconnect()
    end

    local waypointTarget = self.waypoints[self.currentWaypoint].Position
    local humanoid : Humanoid = self.modelRef.Humanoid
    
    self.moveToConnection = humanoid.MoveToFinished:Connect(function(didReach : boolean)
        if not didReach then
            warn("Failed to reach waypoint for some reason, figure out why!")
        end
        
        self.currentWaypoint += 1

        -- if there are no more waypoints, we've made it to the end!
        if self.currentWaypoint > #self.waypoints then
            print(string.format("Enemy should deal %d damage!", self.damage))
            return
        end

        -- walk towards the next waypoint
        self:Walk()
    end)
    self.modelRef.Humanoid:MoveTo(waypointTarget)
end

function Enemy:SetPosition(newPosition : Vector3)
    local waypointTarget = self.waypoints[self.currentWaypoint].Position
    local newPivot = CFrame.new(newPosition, waypointTarget)
    self.modelRef:PivotTo(newPivot)

    -- tell the enemy to start moving towards its next waypoint again.
    self:Walk()
end

function Enemy:OnKnockback(knockbackAmount : number)
    -- take snapshots of values while we calculate
    local waypoints = self.waypoints
    local currentWaypoint = self.currentWaypoint
    local model : Model = self.modelRef
    local position : Vector3 = model:GetPivot().Position

    -- loop as many times as needed, but escape if we're back at the start
    while (currentWaypoint > 1) do

        -- calculate how far it is from the enemy to their previous waypoint
        local distToLastWaypoint : Vector3 = (position - waypoints[currentWaypoint - 1].Position)
        local progress = distToLastWaypoint.Magnitude 

        -- if the distance is greater than the knockback, translate the enemy back towards their previous waypoint
        if (progress >= knockbackAmount) then
            -- reassign values
            self.currentWaypoint = currentWaypoint
            
            -- move to the new position
            local newPosition = position - (distToLastWaypoint.Unit * knockbackAmount)
            self:SetPosition(newPosition)
            
            -- we're done here, escape the loop
            return
        end

        -- subtract their progress from the total knockback amount
        knockbackAmount -= progress
        currentWaypoint -= 1

        -- adjust the position to the last waypoint, and loop as many times as necessary
        position = self.waypoints[currentWaypoint].Position
    end

    -- if we're here, we got pushed all the way back to the beginning
    -- set the position, and start the moveTo again
    self.currentWaypoint = 2
    local newPosition = waypoints[1].Position
    self:SetPosition(newPosition)
end

return Enemy

Then, in your game logic Script you can use it like :
-- services
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Workspace = game:GetService("Workspace") -- not really needed

-- modules
local Enemy = require(ReplicatedStorage.Enemy) -- or wherever you put it

-- fetch the officer model from ReplicatedStorage, and configure some values
local enemyModelTemplate = ReplicatedStorage.Enemies["Handcuff Arrest Officer"]
local health = 10
local speed = 14 -- max studs / second
local damage = 10
local wps = Workspace.Waypoints
local waypoints = { wps["1"], wps["2"], wps["3"] } -- add as many as needed

-- create the enemy
local officerEnemy = Enemy.new(waypoints, damage, speed, health, enemyModelTemplate)
officerEnemy:Spawn()
officerEnemy:Walk()

-- test out the knockback
wait(10.0)
local studsToMove = 5
officerEnemy:OnKnockback(studsToMove)


Whole lot better than mine.

Thanks so much for the answer! I have been recently integrating some features into a main ModuleScript TagFunction that performs special unit abilities (such as knockback). The script chooses a target out of the enemy models that are currently alive. However, since knockback uses a class, I don't know how to call OnKnockback from just a model-I can't figure out how to access the class and its functions. Is this possible?

It's definitely possible! Unfortunately I can't edit my question to show you here, but you just need your tower scripts to communicate with the script that created the enemies. So here are some steps to set that up. 1) Update the spawning Script to give each enemy an ID, and stores all the enemies. 2) Update the Enemy module so that when it spawns the model, it puts a NumberValue or an Attribute in it with that ID. 3) When a tower hits the enemy model, it finds that ID and fires a BindableEvent with that ID. 4) Your Script will listen for that event, lookup the enemy by ID, and knock it back.

You need to change the Humanoid's CFrame after getting it from the player. Here's a example assuming the script is inside a part, and you're getting the player from the Touched event without using the MoveTo method. Here's an example:
local part = script.Parent

part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
     local character = hit.Parent
     local player =   game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)

     if player then
        print(player.Name .. " touched the part!")
     end
 end)


Unfortunately, using this method results in the same problem, likely because MoveTo() is called every 0.1 seconds from the enemy script, so it will be quickly overridden if called somewhere else.

You should then remove the task.wait(.1) line, as it's not nessecery, unless it has some other functionality, in which case please tell me.

That MoveTo() function is specially modified to bypass the 8-second movement timeout, as in https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid.

@O5CommandStandsWithUkraine Ok, then it's probably not best do to it that way. You'd be better off  getting the humaniod object for the player, then moving that. This avoids it but should help with your issue.
